# How to add unique id to sub-document in a document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to add unique id to sub-document in a document in mongoose. My mongoose model sub document is not adding object id.

Comment: can you show your mongoose schema?

Comment: also mongoose by default assigns `_id` more in the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id

Answer (score 0):

Try "new ObjectId()" wherever you want a unique Id. e.g

```
db.news.insert({"name":"political", "group":{"x":new ObjectId(),"type":"breaking"}})
```

I tried this in mongodb 2.4.8  and its working fine.