# Reference to schema (not a particular document) in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

Please, note that this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691102/how-do-you-save-a-reference-to-another-document-in-mongoose), nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978353/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-subdocument-schema-in-mongoose), nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943049/how-to-add-unique-id-to-sub-document-in-a-document-in-mongoose), since what I need is **not a reference to a document** from another collection, but **a reference to the collection itself**.

I'm using [mongoose-schema-extend](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend) to create a hierarchic structure for contents.

Let's say I have this:

```
/**
 * Base class for content
 */
var ContentSchema = new Schema({
  URI: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true, required: true },
  auth: {type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'User'},
  timestamps: {
    creation: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    lastModified: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  }
}, {collection: 'content'}); // The plural form of content is content


/**
 * Pages are a content containing a body and a title
 */
var PageSchema = ContentSchema.extend({
  title: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true, required: true },
  format: {type: String, trim: true, required: true, validate: /^(md|html)$/, default: 'html' },
  body: {type: String, trim: true, required: true}
});

/**
 * Articles are pages with a reference to its author and a list of tags
 * articles may have a summary
 */
var ArticleSchema = PageSchema.extend({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  summary: { type: String },
  tags: { type: [String] }
});
```

Now, I want to create another schema, which is a subtype of content, but which represents a set of contents, like so:

```
/**
 * Content sets are groups of content intended to be displayed by views
 */
var ContentSetSchema = ContentSchema.extend({
  name: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true, required: true },
  description: {type: String },
  content: [{
      source: { type: [OTHER_SCHEMA] }, // <- HERE
      filter: {type: String, trim: true },
      order: {type: String, trim: true }
  }]
})
```

So, the `content` attribute of this schema should be a reference to any of the other schemas.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best I came up whit, was using a string, a discriminator key, and a validator:

```
var ContentSchema = new Schema({
// ...
}, {collection: 'content', discriminatorKey : '_type'});

var ContentSetSchema = ContentSchema.extend({
  // ...
  content: [{
    source: { type: [String], validate: doesItExist }
  }]
});

function doesItExist(type, result) {
  ContentModel.distinct('_type').exec()
  .then((contentTypes) =>
    respond(contentTypes.some((validType) => validType === type)));
}
```

But with this solution (good enough an this moment) I can only create ContentSets for types of content that have already some register in the database.